# Getting Java error when running driver drake

Tags: java, r, renv, drake-r-package

I ran into a problem, while running 'driverdrake' within 'renv', It state that Java is not available. I have updated the java path and using jdk-18.0.1.1. please help me resolve this issue.
Below i have given the codes and the error.

```
    > Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = 'C:\GCAM_V6\JAVA\jdk-18.0.1.1\')

    >devtools::load_all(".")
    Loading gcamdata
    >driver_drake(xmldir = "xml/Other")
    GCAM Data System v5.1
    Found 420 chunks
    Found 4265 chunk data requirements
    Found 2416 chunk data products
    1452 chunk data input(s) not accounted for
    target xml.Other.magicc.xml
    x fail xml.Other.magicc.xml
    Error: target xml.Other.magicc.xml failed.
    diagnose(xml.Other.magicc.xml)$error$message:
    '"java"' not found
    diagnose(xml.Other.magicc.xml)$error$calls:
    run_xml_conversion(set_xml_file_helper(magicc.xml[[1]], file_out("xml/Other/magicc.xml")))
    system2("java", args, stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
    In addition: Warning message:
    Missing files for target xml.Other.magicc.xml:
    xml/Other/magicc.xml
```

i tried to set the java path in rstudio console, but it dindnt work.